# Remove Space between author and subtitle when knitting to powerpoint in RStudio

Tags: r, yaml, rstudio, r-markdown, rnotebook

I am knitting to powerpoint using rmarkdown. I am trying to remove the spacing between the subtitle and the author within the title slide. Here is the following code:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
subtitle: "subtitle"
author: "author"
date: "7/10/2019"
output: powerpoint_presentation
---
```

Here is the screenshot from the powerpoint output:
[image]

You can see that the subtitle and the author YAML fields both **map to the same textbox**.

I ended up creating a custom ppt template and playing around with the sizing of the allowable verticle spacing for the subtitle field, but I did not have any luck on changing removing the spacing. I was able to decrease the font size, which subsequently decreased the spacing, but it is not exactly what I was hoping to do.

So my question is: **Is there a way to remove/change the spacing between the subtitle and the author for the title slide within the YAML header?**

I also posted this on the [R Studio Community Forums](https://community.rstudio.com/t/remove-space-between-author-and-subtitle-when-knitting-to-powerpoint-in-rstudio/35033) yesterday.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?